# kubernetes nginx ingress // health checks not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-health-check

Having a 'working' cluster based on the following example : https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/tree/master/examples/nginx

With the above config for the RC, I keep having the following error when looking at the loadbalancer's backend health check : `This load balancer has no health check, so traffic will be sent to all instances regardless of their status.` Although they do have an healthcheck, and that the default backend is up (deployment & service)

There is a service atop nginx in order to benefit from using static ips on lb ingresses; should this one be healed too ?

Captured here in case : [image]

I might lack of basic knowledge about health checks; but reading the doc did not helped on this to have a clear setup and solve this issue

Help appreciated; best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that LB health checks are part of the gce infra and differ from k8s internal pod healthchecks.

see [Is the Google Container Engine Kubernetes Service LoadBalancer sending traffic to unresponsive hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648176/is-the-google-container-engine-kubernetes-service-loadbalancer-sending-traffic-t)

Comment: Going further (i use kubelego so things are https' redirected), i ended up setting manually a http health check to /healthz (see here : https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/27) which, i have to say with a knowledge i have, seems unuseful to me ( it checks the kubelego but not the lb), meaning apart from providing green circles to the backend pools it doesn't check anything..am i right to think that ?