# Google container engine health checks from service load balancer

Tags: kubernetes-health-check

I have a Network(Service) load balancer on GCP and a kubernetes cluster with a pod that serves traffic on 80,443. How can I create a successful health check so the load balancer marks the nodes healthy? I tried creating health check for port 80, 443 and also opened port 10250 for kubelet and tried health checking http 10250 as suggested in 
[Is the Google Container Engine Kubernetes Service LoadBalancer sending traffic to unresponsive hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648176/is-the-google-container-engine-kubernetes-service-loadbalancer-sending-traffic-t/34661057#34661057?newreg=378a73053c9e4633807ceb47f10fbfbb)